# Why am I getting InvalidArgumentError: H.Map (Argument #0 [object Object])

Tags: javascript, here-api

Below is the code I refactored from the Maps API for JavaScript "Working with React" section. I'm new to React, learning in school, and we have to use functional components. HERE provides guidance in class component syntax, so I'm hoping it's a translation error

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import H from "@here/maps-api-for-javascript";
import {maps} from "./Settings"

export const Map = () => {

  const [map, setMap] = useState()
    // // the reference to the container
    // const ref = React.createRef();
    // // reference to the map
    // const map = null;
   useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) {
      // instantiate a platform, default layers and a map as usual
      const platform = new H.service.Platform({
        apikey: `${maps.apiKey}`
      });
      const layers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
      debugger
      const newMap = new H.Map(
        layers.vector.normal.map,
        {
          pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio,
          center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
          zoom: 2,
        },
      );
      setMap(newMap)
    }
   }, [])


    

    return (
      <div 
      style={{ width: '300px', height:'300px' }}
      {...map}> </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect.

The Argument #0 [object Object] is related to first argument of 'new H.Map(' i.e. layers.vector.normal.map but first argument should be map container e.g. html element div and as second argument should be layers.vector.normal.map.

Your code should look like:

```
import React from 'react';
import H from "@here/maps-api-for-javascript";
import onResize from 'simple-element-resize-detector';

export default class Map extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // the reference to the container
    this.ref = React.createRef();
    // reference to the map
    this.map = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.map) {
      const platform = new H.service.Platform({
        apikey: `${maps.apiKey}`
      });
      const layers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
      const map = new H.Map(
        this.ref.current,
        layers.vector.normal.map,
        {
          pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio,
          center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
          zoom: 2,
        },
      );
      onResize(this.ref.current, () => {
        map.getViewPort().resize();
      });
      this.map = map;
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ position: 'relative', width: '100%', height:'300px' }}
        ref={this.ref}
      />
    )
  }
  
}
```

Please follow the description on https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.26.0/dev_guide/topics/react-practices.html